# Azure web app throws exception in Application Insights: "Merging of ETL Files has failed"

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, appinsights

I see a recurring exception in my App Insights for our Web App.The source is Application Insights profiler

[image]

I followed these 2 links for the solution:

- https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1438
- [Azure web apps throws error Merging of ETL files has failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51979552/azure-web-apps-throws-error-merging-of-etl-files-has-failed)

As per the above links, the version 2.6.5 includes the solution for this error. So I checked the version in our web app and it is "Pre-Installed Site Extension, version 2.8.42.4." I checked this version by using the URL in this format for my web app: https://yoursitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/ApplicationInsights

Below are the configurations in my web app. I'm using .Net 6 framework and the app service plan is for windows.
[image]

Does anyone facing similar error? Any solution or leads will help very much.

Comment: Could you please try to add the following to your App settings: `DiagnosticServices_EXTENSION_VERSION`  and set value as`~3`. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The settings already exist. DiagnosticServices_EXTENSION_VERSION ~3
InstrumentationEngine_EXTENSION_VERSION ~1. Unfortunately I cannot attach a screenshot here.

Comment: Could you please let us know Which App service plan you are using ..

Comment: I'm using Premium v2 Service Plan P1v2 for windows. I share this app service plan with another 3 App services and 2 Azure functions. None of them are throwing this error. The only difference between the others and the one failing was the AppInsights package reference in the .csproj file which I added yesterday, however I still see the exception.